# Laravel Zip Download Mistake

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to simply download a zip file inside my storage directory

My blade view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success download-app" data-download-name="{{ $uploadsValue->name }}">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
</button>
```

My JS with axios

```
download () {
    $('.download-app').click((e) => {
        let _this = $(e.currentTarget);
        axios.post('download/download', {
            name: _this.data('download-name')
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("ERROR");
        })
    });
},
```

My download method in my controller

```
public function download(Request $request)
{
    return response()->download(
        storage_path('/app/uploaded_apps/' . $request->name . '.zip')
    );
}
```

I get no error message I just get this strange output (41352 characters long)

> UEsDBBQAAAAIACFWjEvcpbvIongAAEDyAAAQAAAAcHJpbW9wYXltZW50LkpQR+yXeTyU3d...

Comment: Actually never using axios to download file. But AFAIK downloading file `blob` via ajax request would require extra handler. I hope url give you some hints https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743.